# How to convert a computed binary matrix (mod q) into a decimal matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a binary matrix `X=[[1,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0]]` with modulo q=4, and convert to decimal matrix is `[[3,2],[1,0]]`(bits ordered from least significant to most significant).

Now I want to do some caculations on the binary matrix X, for example, adding 1 to the first column of each row, X becomes `[[2,1,0,1],[2,0,0,0]`. Using ordinary method to convert it to decimal, it will report an error, because 2 is not binary element. How can I restore X to `[[4,1],[2,0]]`, because modulo 4, so X then becomes `[[0,1],[2,0]]`, and can be expanded into a binary matrix?

Comment: How does your "conversion" work? Which bits in the binary matrix forms which decimal in the other matrix? Also what is `q` used for?

Comment: `q` is used to limit the value of the element of the recovered decimal matrix, and I can specify it in advance.`m = int(math.log(q,2))+1` is that `m` bits binary in the matrix form a decimal, here `m=2, q=3`.